# How to call a intent from Node.js for DialogFlow

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am making a app for the Google Assistant and when it runs, i only want 6 people to be able to play. Is there a way to say back to the players "Only say 6 names" and then get input again? I want to use a webhook to remember the names and if it gets more than 6 names, it will call a intent that says only 6 people can play.

Thanks!

Comment: The heading and the body of question do not match.Be specific on where you are struck,also post the code you have tried.

Comment: So you want to integrate Dialogflow with a webhook?

Comment: I have updated the information on the question but I have no code as I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an intent that captures a list of names, you should just return a response from your webhook that tells the user that they've input too many names and that they should try again.

Since your original intent already captures a list of names, it will be triggered a second time when they input their amended list.